# How to remove CKeditor4 parahraph tag when I press enter button?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, editor, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor5

I don't want p tag when I press enter in keyboard. I want BR when I press enter. I see some suggetions they are told make some changes in your config.js file. But I don't have config.js file actually **I used CDN link or CDN tag**. **I am also try**

```
<script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.14.0/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('#your_textarea').ckeditor({
      toolbar: 'Full',
      enterMode : CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR,
      shiftEnterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_P
    }); 
  });
</script>
```

**code in my header section.** But same problem It's hot work Showing Eror in my console :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at VM560 addsongs:33

May you please help me and give me a better way that I can utilized in my page.

Comment: have you included `jQuery` library?

Comment: Yes. I am inclide 'jquery.min.js'